# Is it possible to get the value of the type argument passed in to an object as <T> where T : class?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a `List<AbstractParentClass<T>>`, the abstract parent class declares that the Type Argument must be a class(AbstractParentClass where T: class). Am I able to obtain the value of the Type Argument that is used by the concrete instances of the abstract class?

Definition of parent class

```
abstract class ParentClass<T> where T: class
```

Example of child of parent

```
public class ChildClass : ParentClass<TypeArgumentClass>
```

What Im trying to accomplish:

```
List<ParentClass> objects = InstantiateObjects(...non relevant arguments...)
```

Here is where I would be hoping to reference the Type Arg if possible:

```
var firstIndexTypeArg = objects[0].{TypeArgument}
```

Comment: `List<ParentClass>` isn't valid, you would need a `GrandParent` class and then `abstract class ParentClass<T> : GrandParent`

Comment: Agree, you should make the question more precise. If you do as @Charlieface suggests, and if what you want is a `System.Type` reflection instance (but for what?), then you could give `GrandParent` a property `public abstract Type TypeArg { get; }` which could then be implemented as `public sealed override Type TypeArg => typeof(T);` in `ParentClass<T>`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That is, oddly enough, the exact code I'm working on at the moment in my own project, on my screen now.

Comment: Seems like you want to have different kind of objects in a single list. How would consumers of that list ever know what instances they get? That's a really bad idea. Don't put different things into a single list. A `List<Derived>` has *nothing* in common with a `List<Parent>`. You probably don't want this to work `((List<Animals)myGiraffes).Add(new Lion())`, do you?

Comment: why not do `objects[0].GetType().GetGenericArguments[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have a type called `Fruit`.

Let's say I have two subtypes, `Apple` and `Banana`.

Assuming that I have an instance of `List<Apple>` then I cannot cast it to `List<Fruit>` because that would let me add a `Banana` to a `List<Apple>` - and that would be bad!

To make it more real, here's the code:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Apple> apples = new List<Apple>();
    List<Fruit> fruit = apples;
    fruit.Add(new Banana());
}

public abstract class Fruit { }
public class Apple : Fruit { }
public class Banana : Fruit { }
```

The compiler complains on the cast, as it should do:

[image: Fruit]

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this. In fact, `List<ParentClass>` isn't possible anyway, as you haven't specified the type argument.

Instead, you need a `GrandParent` class

```cs
abstract class GrandParent
{
    // non-generic fields/methods here
}

abstract class ParentClass<T> : GrandParent where T : class
{
    // generic fields/methods here
}

class ChildClass : ParentClass<TypeArgumentClass>
{
    // whatever
}
```

Now you can do this

```cs
List<GrandParent> objects = InstantiateObjects();
```

where `InstantiateObjects` is declared something like this

```
List<GrandParent> InstantiateObjects()
{
    var list = new List<GrandParent>();
    foreach (var sometype in something)
        list.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(someType));
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Unless we know the type returned by `InstantiateObjects()` we can't know that this is the answer.

Comment: See new edit...